# Http instant https firebase functions

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

I have a client who wants to access our API via C++ in a Cancel terminal, but they are unable to make the call via https, is it possible for me to allow firebase functions to accept http calls instead of https?

Testing in Postman I can access the API resources via https, but when I change to http I get the error below:

Server
https://us-central1-selfparking-prod-26925.cloudfunctions.net/gate/ticket

[image]

Comment: http is not secure, there's no reason to try to downgrade. There's another issue that needs to be resolved but can't say with the provided information

Comment: What do you mean "unable to make the call via https"? I would focus on solving that problem first.  https is everywhere and all programming environments should be able to use it.  It's very confusing to me that someone would not be able to.  Please edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect along with instructions that anyone can follow to duplicate the problem.

Comment: What is a `Cancel terminal`? Google is HTTPS everywhere. In your case, if you make an HTTP request to your endpoint, the Google GFE will return a 302 status with an HTTP `Location` header pointing to your HTTPS endpoint. You cannot get around that. I am guessing that your client wants to use raw sockets to make HTTP requests. Your client will need to upgrade/enhance their development environment to implement TLS (SSL). A common library to use is `openssl` but there are several other good ones such as BoringSSL (Google). On Windows, `SChannel` is often used.